# rasm2 output differs from radare2

Tags: radare2

`radare2` disassembles an instruction in the following way ([binary here](http://crackmes.de/users/sx0r/crackme4_by_sx0r/download)):

```
0x0040425f 0f847b020000   je 0x4044e0
```

Why is giving `rasm2` different result?

```
rasm2 -a x86 -b 64 -d '0f847b020000'
je 0x281
```

Comment: Please give some reasons why you downvoted my question.

Comment: I am just curious. Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 5):

```
rasm2 -d -o 0x40425f 0f847b020000
je 0x4044e0
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is a different result, only a different representation.
The `radare2` output tells you at which absolute address will the jump take you (in this case `0x004044e0`), while the `rasm2` output tells you how far from the current address (in this case `0x0040425f`) will the jump take you.

To make it more clear: Your current instruction starts at address `0x0040425f`, while your destination address is `0x004044e0`. If you substitute the two addresses you get: `0x004044e0 - 0x0040425f = 0x00000281`, which is the parameter to the jump in the `rasm2` tool.

Also, the opcode `0x0F 0x84` stands for `JE rel16/rel32` and since you haven't specified at which address your instruction `0f847b020000` resides the `rasm2` tool is correctly telling you that it is `0x281` bytes from wherever the instruction is: `parameter_value(0x0000027b) + instruction_length(0x06) = 0x00000281`